# GAWK is counting FS as fields

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I want to parse the following text so that each line contains one field (all the text excluding tags):

```
<tag>first line</tag>
<tag>second line</tag>
```

To do so, I used this GAWK script:

```
BEGIN{FS="</?tag>";}
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){print "field " i "->" $i;}}
END{}
```

I was expecting this output:

```
field 1->first line
field 1->second line
```

And instead, I got this:

```
field 1->
field 2->first line
field 3->
field 1->
field 2->second line
field 3->
```

Can someone explain what is being captured under fields $1 and $3? I have also tried to use `FS="</?tag>\n?"`, but I got the same output.

Comment: in your expected output each field always numbered with `1`. Thus, no need to loop though all fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the value of `FS`, to Awk, the line `<tag>first line</tag>` looks like this:

> ```
> field1 delimiter field2 delimiter field3
> ```

A simple workaround is to drop the loop, and simply print `$2`, if you know that there will only ever be one "field" per line:

```
BEGIN {FS = "</?tag>"} {print $2}
```

Comment: In that case, the output would only be 'nothing'. I want to make a FS so that to AWK, the line <tag>first line</tag> looks like this: 'delimiter field1 delimiter'.

Comment: @FrVentura ah, I really meant `print $2`. Corrected it now, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Given this file with `FS=","`

```
a,b,c
```

What's in field 1? It's `"a"`, right?

Now given this file with `FS="</?tag>"`:

```
a<tag>b</tag>c
```

What's in field 1? Still `"a"`.

Now given this file with the same `FS="</?tag>"`:

```
<tag>b</tag>c
```

What's in field 1? Now it's the null string (`""`).

Now given this file with the same `FS="</?tag>"`:

```
<tag>first line</tag>
```

What's in field 1? Still `""` and ditto for field 3.

As [@janos said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735684/1745001), just `print $2`, or if what you REALLY want is to use just `</tag>` as the FS but strip the associated leading `<tag>` from each field then that'd be:

```
$ awk -v FS='</tag>' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (sub(/.*<tag>/,"",$i)) print i, $i }' file
1 first line
1 second line
```

which arguably has more intuitive behavior when you have multiple fields in a line:

```
$ cat file
<tag>line 1, field 1</tag><tag>line 1, field 2</tag>
<tag>line 2, field 1</tag><tag>line 2, field 2</tag><tag>line 2, field 3</tag>

$ awk -v FS='</tag>' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (sub(/.*<tag>/,"",$i)) print NR, NF, i, $i; print "" }' file
1 3 1 line 1, field 1
1 3 2 line 1, field 2

2 4 1 line 2, field 1
2 4 2 line 2, field 2
2 4 3 line 2, field 3

$ awk -v FS='</?tag>' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NR, NF, i, $i; print "" }' file
1 5 1
1 5 2 line 1, field 1
1 5 3
1 5 4 line 1, field 2
1 5 5

2 7 1
2 7 2 line 2, field 1
2 7 3
2 7 4 line 2, field 2
2 7 5
2 7 6 line 2, field 3
2 7 7

$ awk -v FS='</?tag>' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print NR, NF, i, $i; print "" }' file
1 5 2 line 1, field 1
1 5 4 line 1, field 2

2 7 2 line 2, field 1
2 7 4 line 2, field 2
2 7 6 line 2, field 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. However, I do not understand how the file text ' a b c' with default FS doesn't produce fields with null strings. Using the same logic, it should.

Comment: You're welcome. You can't apply the same logic though because the default FS isn't treated the same way as every other FS. Specifically, given an FS of the default blank char (`" "`), all leading and trailing white space are stripped from the record before field splitting occurs and then the record is broken into fields at all contiguous chains of white space. To use a literal `" "` as the separator you'd need `FS="[ ]"`. A glance at the man page would tell you that - see, for example, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators.